# Violation of Unique Key constraint in C# application when updating

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a table called `Contact` in a SQL Server database. The only primary key is `contactID`. Here is the part of the script used to create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[contact]
(
    [contactID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [lName] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [fName] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [dob] [date] NOT NULL,
    [mailingAddressStreet] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [mailingAddressCity] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [mailingAddressState] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [mailingAddressZip] [char](5) NOT NULL,
    [phoneNumber] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [gender] [char](1) NULL,
    [SSN] [char](9) NOT NULL,
    [userType] [int] NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([contactID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Here is the method I am using in C# to execute the update:

```
public static bool UpdatePatient(int contactID, string lastName, string firstName, DateTime DOB, string street, string city, string state, 
            string ZIP, string phone, string gender, string SSN)
{
    bool isUpdated = false;

    string updateStmt = "UPDATE contact SET lName = @lastName, fName = @firstName, dob = @DOB, mailingAddressStreet = @street, " +
                "mailingAddressCity = @city, mailingAddressState = @state, mailingAddressZip = @ZIP, phoneNumber = @phone, gender = @gender, ssn = @SSN " +
                "WHERE contactID = @contactID";

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connect = DBConnection.GetConnection())
        {
            connect.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateStmt, connect))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactID", contactID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", DOB);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@street", street);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", city);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", state);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZIP", ZIP);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phone);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SSN", SSN);

                isUpdated = (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0);
            }

            connect.Close();
        }

        return isUpdated;
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlex)
    {
        throw sqlex;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I know that the view is passing the correct parameters in, so that's not a problem. However, when I am running my application and attempt to update someone's contact information, I get an error like this:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint UQ_contact_CA1E8E3C4CEC5645. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.contact'. The duplicate key value is (333222112).

That number "333222112" is the SSN (completely made-up for testing purposes, of course). When running the update though as a test, I am actually leaving the SSN unchanged. However, the functionality to include the SSN is important in case it needs to be corrected after a typo. The update form has all the contact information already pre-populated, and it is up to the user to make whatever changes they want before clicking the button to update, which calls this method.

Comment: Do you have a unique index on SSN?

Comment: Yes, it does. The SSN should be unique, but it should also be something that can be updated in case it needs to be corrected.

Comment: Can you run `SELECT * FROM contact WHERE SSN = '333222112'` on your database? It must exist already, surely?

Comment: It does exist. It's unique but not a primary key, so it should still be something that can be updated, right?

Comment: You do know that unique means unique, right? Well, unique _constraints_. It isn't only primary keys that can be unique in this way: [unique indexes/constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-unique-indexes#Benefits)

Comment: I know what unique means, but why can't I update it from one unique value to a totally different unique value? It seems like the old unique value would no longer exist, and the new unique value should then be present, assuming of course that the new value doesn't already exist.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. It sounded like the value existed on a different row. I'm still tempted to think it does.